# Checking for numeric value in field + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What would be the most efficient way to check for numbers in a field that would contain a few letters? I would like to do this if the where statement as possible.

The data would look something like this:

3833N4323
32N907654
5W5840904

Comment: Are you checking whether numbers exist in the field?  Do you wish to extract those numbers?

Comment: Just checking to make sure theres numbers in the field and will then  selecting whats in there in its entirety.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Checking for at least one number in a field (corrected):

```
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', field) != 0
```

Checking for only numbers in a field:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(field AS int) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: how is this?

AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', pq.ReportNumber) > 1

Comment: You have the REGEXP keyword on SQL Server? What version of SQL Server is that?

Comment: This seems to work.

AND PATINDEX('%[0-9^]%', pq.ReportNumber) > 1

Comment: The last block of code will not work.  It needs to be changed to 
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(field) = 1

Answer (score 10):

A simple LIKE to find any number will suffice...

```
...WHERE LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select ISNUMERIC(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this value: 33465,33465 , returns 1 ( number with a comma, which in my case I consider a string, not the kind of numbers I want to allow )

Comment: In 'my' Microsoft SQL Server 2019 version all of these return 1: select ISNUMERIC('$'), ISNUMERIC(','), ISNUMERIC('-'). Also select ISNUMERIC('123123123E1') -notice the E near the end- returns 1. However, ISNUMERIC('123123123F1') -now with an F- returns 0. It seems you cannot really rely on this function.